# WPF Button with Image and Text (with the whole button clickable)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, devexpress

I have a button with XAML code with Devexpress as follows:

```
<dxlc:LayoutItem Width="80" Margin="0,0,0,0">
   <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ob:ViewModel}}, Path=DataContext.ClickCommand}"  ToolTip="CLick this button"
             Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DimGray">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="../../../Resources/Ext/image.png" MaxHeight="16" MinHeight="16" Stretch="Uniform" />
        <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="Click Me" IsReadOnly="True" ShowBorder="False" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent"/>
     </StackPanel>
   </Button>
 </dxlc:LayoutItem>
```

With this code, only the border of the button is clickable and not the area with the Text. How can I have an image next to a button and have the whole area of the button be clickable?

Comment: Set Background="Transparent" on the StackPanel.

Comment: @Clemens That didn't do it, but changing the TextEdit to a TextBlock did, which is good enough for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like WPF was having some trouble with my TextEdit, so I just changed it to **TextBlock** and it is now part of the button and clickable.

Answer (score 1):

WPF mouse event is RoutedEvent and bubbling in visual tree, but some control behaviors may stop event bubbling.
In the native control, a `TextBox` in the `Button` will intercept the click event, click `TextBox` will not trigger `Button` click event.
Please use the correct controls to build the UI of your software.